# SQLITE: INTERSECT / UNION Select Result & Normal Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I use the solution below at the moment, the result is what I expected now.

```
myIDArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
...
executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""
            "SELECT name"
            "  FROM TABLE_A"
            " WHERE a_id IN ("
            "     SELECT b_id"
            "       FROM TABLE_B"
            " )"
            "   AND a_id IN %@", myIDArray];
```

But I wonder **is there any way to `INTERSECT` two id lists inner `IN (?)`**? Like

```
executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""
            "SELECT name"
            "  FROM TABLE_A"
            " WHERE a_id IN ("
            "     SELECT b_id"
            "       FROM TABLE_B"
            "  INTERSECT"
            "         %@"// how to put my id array here appropriately?
            " )", myIDArray];
```

Of course, this does not work, will throw syntax error.

I've also tried to use `-componentsJoinedByString:` to convert the array to string, w/ or w/o `()` for the string. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

INTERSECT would require a query, so you would need a query that returns all these values:

```sql
... IN (SELECT b_id FROM TableB
        INTERSECT
        SELECT id FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
                        SELECT 2       UNION ALL
                        ...
                        SELECT 42));
```

This is more verbose and less efficient than using two INs.

Comment: Ic.. so seems there's no way to put the array directly.. thx anyway. :)